# Obtain visible scale/range of axis

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using Arction LightningChartJs I would like to know how to obtain the current scale/range of the visible x axis in a progressively scrolling axis.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX().scale.getInnerStart();//Returns the start of the x axis
chart.getDefaultAxisX().scale.getInnerEnd();//Returns the end of the x axis
```

The chart class has the scale property which inturn has methods to retrieve the start and end points at the time these methods are triggered.